# Adding html5 audio player to cms made simple

Tags: cmsmadesimple

Hi I bought a html 5 audio player bit of code and uploaded it to the server and works fine in html page but trying to put into the cms site with a template is another mater.

I need to copy over code to put in the head and body tags.

Would I be correct that the html would go into the template?
so copy the template and put it into that.

Is the JavaScript ok in the head tag or does need to go into page metatags?

Been unable to find a module that can play mp3 files as a playlist and is cross browser compatible and can play on android and apple os.

This player does all that and has flash fallback but no joy getting it to work in the cms.

Any help would be very gratefully received

Jamski

Answer (score 0):

Yes you add the HTML to your template.  Javascript is OK in the template or the metatags but you need to enclose the javascript code in `{literal}literal tags like this{/literal}` - this stops your javascript being interpretted as Smarty.

There are some player modules in the forge on the CMSMS website.